# Call a stored procedure, passing a valid school ID and a leader score of 50, but procedure doesn't work

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, sql-update

I have written a SQL IF statement to update the stored procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE UPDATE_LEADERS_SCORE (
    IN in_School_ID  INTEGER, IN in_Leader_Score INTEGER) 

LANGUAGE SQL 
MODIFIES SQL DATA

  BEGIN
  
    UPDATE SCHOOLS
    SET Leaders_Score = in_Leader_Score
    WHERE School_ID = in_School_ID;
       
    IF in_Leader_Score > 0 and in_Leader_Score < 20 THEN  
        UPDATE SCHOOLS
        SET Leaders_Icon = 'Very_weak'
        WHERE School_ID = in_School_ID;
    ELSEIF in_Leader_Score >=20 and in_Leader_Score < 40  THEN
        UPDATE SCHOOLS
        SET Leaders_Icon = 'Weak'
        WHERE School_ID = in_School_ID;
    ELSEIF in_Leader_Score >=40 and in_Leader_Score < 60 THEN
        UPDATE SCHOOLS
        SET Leaders_Icon = 'Average'
        WHERE School_ID = in_School_ID;
    ELSEIF in_Leader_Score >=60 and in_Leader_Score < 80 THEN
        UPDATE SCHOOLS
        SET Leaders_Icon = 'Strong'
        WHERE School_ID = in_School_ID;
    ELSEIF in_Leader_Score >=80 and in_Leader_Score < 100 THEN
        UPDATE SCHOOLS
        SET Leaders_Icon = 'Very_strong'
        WHERE School_ID = in_School_ID;
        END IF;
  END 
  @
```

but when I call the stored procedure, it doesn't work

```
CALL UPDATE_LEADERS_SCORE(609676, 50);
```

And I have errors like :

```
Message d'erreur
Value "Average" is too long.. SQLCODE=-433, SQLSTATE=22001, DRIVER=4.27.25
```

Does anyone have ideas?

Comment: what is the datatype Leaders_Icon

Comment: the datatype of Leaders_Icon is VARCHAR

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (The above code is product specific.)

Comment: Looks like DB2.  Leaders_Icon is VARCHAR.. Are you sure? Not VARCHAR(10)or something like that, but VARCHAR? Varchar without length is VARCHAR(1).

Comment: i'm using DB2 Cloud

Comment: the datatype of Leaders_Icon is VARCHAR(11)

Answer (score 0):

Your function code performance will be slow. Because in your code `update` command will be executed on 2 times. It is possible to write this function very simply and with high performance.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE update_leaders_score(in_school_id integer, in_leader_score integer)
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $procedure$
begin

    update schools 
    SET 
        leaders_score = in_leader_score, 
        leaders_icon = 
        case 
            when (in_leader_score > 0   and in_leader_score < 20)   then 'Very_weak'
            when (in_leader_score >= 20 and in_leader_score < 40)   then 'Weak'
            when (in_leader_score >= 40 and in_leader_score < 60)   then 'Average'
            when (in_leader_score >= 60 and in_leader_score < 80)   then 'Strong'
            when (in_leader_score >= 80 and in_leader_score < 100)  then 'Very_strong'
        end 
    WHERE school_id = in_school_id;

END;
$procedure$
;
```

Answer (score 0):

Increase the length of the Leaders_Icon by using below code before calling stored procedure, It will work.

ALTER TABLE SCHOOLS ALTER COLUMN Leaders_Icon SET DATA TYPE VARCHAR(20);

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I confirm that the issue is not enough characters are allocated, as kindly suggested by @user17565261

The following columns to be altered:
ALTER TABLE CHICAGO_PUBLIC_SCHOOLS ALTER COLUMN Leaders_Icon SET DATA TYPE VARCHAR(20);
ALTER TABLE CHICAGO_PUBLIC_SCHOOLS ALTER COLUMN Leaders_Score SET DATA TYPE VARCHAR(20);

To run the code kindly provided by @Ramin Faracov on IBM Db2, the following format will do

```
--#SET TERMINATOR @
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE update_leaders_score_1 (in_school_id integer, in_leader_score integer)
LANGUAGE sql

begin

    update chicago_public_schools
    SET 
        leaders_score = in_leader_score, 
        leaders_icon = 
        case 
            when (in_leader_score > 0   and in_leader_score < 20)   then 'Very_weak'
            when (in_leader_score >= 20 and in_leader_score < 40)   then 'Weak'
            when (in_leader_score >= 40 and in_leader_score < 60)   then 'Average'
            when (in_leader_score >= 60 and in_leader_score < 80)   then 'Strong'
            when (in_leader_score >= 80 and in_leader_score < 100)  then 'Very_strong'
        end 
    WHERE school_id = in_school_id;

END
@
```